# Display characters other than alphabets using reqular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have tried to display characters other than alphabets in the particular string but it is displaying only the first char.

```
var myArray = /[^a-zA-Z]+/g.exec("cdAbb#2547dbsbz78678");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
"cdAbb#2547dbsbz78678".match(/[^a-zA-Z]+/g).join('');
//=> #254778678
```

`RegExp.exec` with `g` (global) modifier needs to run in loop to give you all the matches.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is only displaying the first character is because with using `exec` and the `g` modifier (global),  this method is meant to be used in a loop for getting all sub matches.

```
var str = "cdAbb#2547dbsbz78678";
var re  = /[^a-zA-Z]+/g;
var myArray;

while (myArray = re.exec(str)) {
  console.log(myArray[0]);
}
```

Output

```
#2547
78678
```

If you were wanting to combine the matches you could use the following.

```
var str = "cdAbb#2547dbsbz78678",
    res = str.match(/[\W\d]+/g).join('');

# => "#254778678"
```

Or do a replacement

```
str = str.replace(/[a-z]+/gi, '');
```

Comment: How so? There is no need for it. `\W` matches non word characters and `\d` matches digits, OP stated "other than alphabets"

Comment: Sorry its me, i don't have well understand the question!